# Read Facebook group feed and events WITHOUT login using PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, wordpress, facebook-php-sdk

I'm actually trying to build a Wordpress facebook feed plugin for my personal site. I tried using a third party plugin and it didn't work out so I'm building my own so I can customize it to my needs. I'm having a hard time it seems understanding their authentication scheme. All the examples I see show a redirect or callback URL for logging into Facebook. I DO NOT want users that visit my site to have to login to Facebook for anything. I just want them to view a feed from a group and that group's events. I created an app with the user_groups, read_stream, and manage_pages permissions. I do not need the ability to post or like, just read status/posts and events. Reading the feed seems to work fine, however, reading events seems to require an extended token but I'm unclear as to how to maintain that (I had to login, get a user token etc). Note the group in question is public and events are public. Here is my setup:

```
        $app_id = 'my-fb-app-id';
        $app_secret = 'my-fb-app-secret';
        $groupId = 'myGroupId';
        FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($app_id, $app_secret);
        $session = FacebookSession::newAppSession();
        $accessToken = $session->getAccessToken();
        $session = new FacebookSession( $accessToken );
    //this works fine
        $request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', "/{$groupId}/feed");
    //this throws exception: A user access token is required to request this resource. 
        //$request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', "/{$groupId}/events?fields=location,end_time,name"); 
        $response = $request->execute();
        $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
//Just returning from plugin for debugging purposes
        echo '<pre>' . print_r($graphObject, 1) . '</pre>';
```

So the question is: what am I missing here? Why do I need a user access token to read group events? The only way I got this to work is by using an extended token just to read events. Also, if in fact I do need an extended token to read the group events, I don't know how to get and maintain an extended token. I had to login to my app page and get the app's access token. Is there a way to get a token that NEVER expires?

Answer (score 1):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page/events say: "Any access token can be used to view publicly shared events" so just use an app access token.

Comment: I can't use an app access token keep getting the following error when I setup my session using App ID, App Secret:
"A user access token is required to request this resource."

Comment: What request are you making then?

Comment: Please see sample code above. I'm assuming the getAccessToken() method gives the token you are talking about. Per above, this is the request I'm making that fails:

$request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', "/{$groupId}/events?fields=location,end_time,name");

Comment: Interesting, apparently page events are not the same as group events: 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/group/events 
Can someone explain to me how I need to setup my call so I can successfully retrieve my groups events?

Comment: For group events you need a user access token. And that token will need to be renewed at least every 60 days